# Why doesn't Xcode recognize my push certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

I've just finished my app, and so I am now getting ready to submit. But I need to change my developer Push certificate to Ad Hoc to test it with a Production Push certificate.

I thought I had it all figured out, but when I build the app, I get the error:
"Failed to get the task for process 2023" (The number changes every time I build.)

I have created my provisioning profile, and I am able to navigate to my Project's Build Settings and set the app to use my Ad Hoc profile. However, when I attempt to set my Code Signing Identity to "Apple Production Services..." all I see is my Distribution Certificate, not the Push Certificate.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I actually did have everything done correctly the first time. I just didn't know that I couldn't build on my phone through Xcode using an Ad Hoc provisioning profile.

So I ended up testing it by downloading the Beta via iTunes.

Answer (score -1):

1. First of all, when you transfer all the Development Certificates to the Production you cant build the project from Xcode.
2. No one see push certificate in code signing identity.
   You only see Either Development certificate or Distribution certificate depending upon the provision profile you have selected. You don't have to worry to choose Push notification certificate in Xcode, coz its managed by Apple once you enabled the push Notification service to the app by enabling it with unique bundle identifier in developer account. https://developer.apple.com (Only you have to give the merged version of that APNS certificate and distribution certificate in .pem format to web developer )
3. For Adhoc You have to generate Ipa of your project form xcode and install in you mobile through external link like http://www.diawi.com, if you import Ipa into your device from iTunes remote push notification will not arrive.